# Get Parent From Child Scope

Tags: c#, oop

How can I get/set an Object from a parent from a child's scope?

```
class Parent
{
    var pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
       ...
    class  Child
    {
        List<string, PictureBox> list;

        Child()
        {
            list.Add("000", /*Here I want to get the Parent elements PictureBox1 instant*/);
               etc.
            // I also set it later
            list[0].Item2.Text = "newPicture";
        }
    }
}
```

So this way I implement these things, and my question is how can I get from Child scope to the Parent.pictureBox1 element.

Comment: Classes defines data structures and behavior. Instances of the classes do not know about classes hierarchy. Usually it's not wright to declare one class in another. It seems as bad architecture.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in C#.

You need to pass the pictureBox to the Child class.
See this link:
[C# nested classes are like C++ nested classes, not Java inner classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/01/685248.aspx)